# How to configure JWT auth and API-KEY auth for spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, jwt

I'm trying to have API-Key authentication for the `/api` part of my app. The rest should have JWT authentication.

The following is not working:

```
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .and()
                .antMatcher("/api/**")
                .addFilter(apiKeyAuthFilter).authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .addFilter(JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

    }
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What is it doing that it's not supposed to?